# Nesting branches in Git

Tags: git, github, synchronization

I have a repository on GitHub that has two branches, namely `master` and `gh-pages`. The `master` branch is basically a static website, but I use GitHub pages to have a project page with a "demo" button that lets the user see what the interface looks like. The project is a [LightDM greeter theme](http://blender3d.github.com/Bevel/), which can be run in the browser as well as by LightDM's Webkit greeter.

Only `gh-pages` can serve the HTML to the browser normally, but I keep all my work on the `master` branch.

My file structure is like this:

```
.
├── theme (master)
|   ├── index.html
|   └── ...
└── website (gh-pages)
    ├── demo -> contents of ../theme/
    ├── index.html
    └── ...
```

I tried symlinking `demo` to `theme`, as the two must contain the exact same contents, but Git responds with this error:

```
Project/website [ git commit -a "Made some changes"
fatal: 'demo/' is beyond a symbolic link
```

Next, I made hooks that synced the contents of `theme` and `demo` whenever I made a commit on either of the branches, but this method seems unnaturally complicated.

I'm basically trying to keep `theme` and `demo` linked to one another. Is there a clean way of doing this using Git?

Answer (score 1):

I think the symlink is the cleanest solution, except:

- it should be ignored (if not, you will always get the "`beyond a symbolic link`" error)
- it should be generated automatically on checkout, through a **[post-checkout hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)**

The problem with hooks is that there aren't cloned around, so the user would still have to activate that specific hook.
Plus that may conflict with an existing post-checkout hook a user might have.

Another solution that won't conflict with any existing hook (but which will still need to be activated by said user cloning your repo) is a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728):

[image: content filter driver]

When looking at the recognizable content of a specific file within `website`, you can decide to create that symlink.
The idea is that a content filter driver script (here a 'smudge' script) is something you can register in a `.gitattributes` file.
But the user will still need to declare that filter driver in his/her git config.